# Do I need to setup a scrolling handler for Firebase utils?

Tags: firebase

I'm looking at using the infinite scroll from the [Firebase utils](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/blob/master/src/Paginate/README.md).

I see I can call `scrollRef.scroll.next(25);` to grab the next 25 records whenever I want to. What I'm not sure, is do I have to setup an event handler for scrolling that calls this method? Or does the [opts] listen for scroll events? `Firebase.util.Scroll(ref, orderByField [, opts]);`. The docs mention `windowSize` but I'm not clear how this works or if it's related to this question.

I'm using React, so I'd probably go with [react-scroll-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-components) if I had to trigger adding new records myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to setup a scrolling handler yourself and trigger `next()` based on the user's scroll position. The `windowSize` option you're referring to is the maximum number of records to have loaded in the list at any given time, which is not really related.